# How to allow camera access on Chrome version 90.0.4430.93 using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpUio.png)

I want to allow camera permission for website "https://webcamtests.com/"

I try use :  `options.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");`

or

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        HashMap<String, Integer> contentSetting = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        HashMap<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();


        contentSetting.put("media_stream",1);
        profile.put("managed_default_content_settings",contentSetting);
        prefs.put("profile",profile);
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs",prefs);
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://webcamtests.com/");
```

But it does not work, I don't know why

Comment: Were any errors generated that could be included with your question?

Comment: no errors, but i can not allow camera permission, i don't know why